# Form of series solution in Differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Find the equation that doesn't have a series solution in form of 
$$y(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nx^n $$

### $$ 1.\;\;\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}+\frac{\sin x}{x}y=0 \qquad 2.\;\;\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}+\frac{\cos x}{x}y=0$$ $$ 3.\;\;\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}+{\sin(x)}y=0\qquad 4.\;\;\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}+{\cos(x)}y=0$$

---

$y''+P(x)y'+Q(x)y=0  $

It seems $Q(x)$ in every choice is analytic to me. How should I solve it?

Comment: whats the limit $\cos(x)/x$ as $x\to 0$?

Comment: In one of these choices, $Q(x)$ is not analytic at $x=0$

Comment: Isn't cosx/x representable as power series which means analytic?

Comment: Try to find the power series of $\cos x/x$. You'll see that the leading term is $1/x$

Comment: @NKYu Dylan is right..try to write the Taylor serie of $\frac {\cos x}x$ and see what happens

Comment: I see the point. Thank you!

Comment: @NKYu Do the same calculation for $\frac {\sin x }x$ and see the difference.